# How to assign CRS to Raster layer obtained from .HDF in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, trmm

I obtained monthly TRMM data (TMPA/3B43) from [here](https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B43.7/1998/). It is in .HDF format for each month. I need it for other algorithm in R that uses netCDF file on yearly basis, so I wrote a code that reads .HDF file, converts it to .tif file (with the help of [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36795219/13818750)), then reads it as raster and converts it to matrix.

The produced raster file (rast) doesn't have a geographical reference. What I understood so far is I have to assign the crs from the southwest corner to (-180,-50) with an interval 0.25 deg in both direction.

Latitude should be from the left: -50 to 49.75 by 0.25 will result in 400 columns
Longitude should be from the bottom -180 to 179.75 by 0.25 will result in 1440 rows

My Question: how to assign this type of CRS to the raster in R? Below are the information of .HDF, .tiff, and matrix.

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)

#use R wrapper for the 'gdalinfo' function to obtain metadata
> gdalinfo("3B43.19980101.7.HDF")
[1] "Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4"                                                  
[2] "Files: 3B43.19980101.7.HDF"                                    
[3] "Size is 512, 512"                                                                                 
[4] "Metadata:"                                                                                        
[5] "  FileHeader=AlgorithmID=3B43;"                                                                   
[6] "AlgorithmVersion=3B43_7.0;"                                                                       
[7] "FileName=3B43.19980101.7.HDF;"                                                                    
[8] "GenerationDateTime=2012-05-14T16:29:45.000Z;"                                                     
[9] "StartGranuleDateTime=1998-01-01T00:00:00.000Z;"                                                   
[10] "StopGranuleDateTime=1998-01-31T23:59:59.999Z;"                                                    
[11] "GranuleNumber=;"                                                                                  
[12] "NumberOfSwaths=0;"                                                                                
[13] "NumberOfGrids=1;"                                                                                 
[14] "GranuleStart=;"                                                                                   
[15] "TimeInterval=MONTH;"                                                                              
[16] "ProcessingSystem=PPS;"                                                                            
[17] "ProductVersion=7;"                                                                                
[18] "MissingData=;"                                                                                    
[19] ""                                                                                                 
[20] "  FileInfo=DataFormatVersion=m;"                                                                  
[21] "TKCodeBuildVersion=1;"                                                                            
[22] "MetadataVersion=m;"                                                                               
[23] "FormatPackage=HDF Version 4.2 Release 4, January 25, 2009;"                                       
[24] "BlueprintFilename=TRMM.V7.3B43.blueprint.xml;"                                                    
[25] "BlueprintVersion=BV_13;"                                                                          
[26] "TKIOVersion=1.6;"                                                                                 
[27] "MetadataStyle=PVL;"                                                                               
[28] "EndianType=LITTLE_ENDIAN;"                                                                        
[29] ""                                                                                                 
[30] "  GridHeader=BinMethod=ARITHMETIC_MEAN;"                                                          
[31] "Registration=CENTER;"                                                                             
[32] "LatitudeResolution=0.25;"                                                                         
[33] "LongitudeResolution=0.25;"                                                                        
[34] "NorthBoundingCoordinate=50;"                                                                      
[35] "SouthBoundingCoordinate=-50;"                                                                     
[36] "EastBoundingCoordinate=180;"                                                                      
[37] "WestBoundingCoordinate=-180;"                                                                     
[38] "Origin=SOUTHWEST;"                                                                                
[39] ""                                                                                                 
[40] "Subdatasets:"                                                                                     
[41] "  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:\"/BE70E3A0F5C15471/TRMM/3B43.19980101.7.HDF\":0"
[42] "  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1440x400] precipitation (32-bit floating-point)"                             
[43] "  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:\"/BE70E3A0F5C15471/TRMM/3B43.19980101.7.HDF\":1"
[44] "  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1440x400] relativeError (32-bit floating-point)"                             
[45] "  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:\"/BE70E3A0F5C15471/TRMM/3B43.19980101.7.HDF\":2"
[46] "  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[1440x400] gaugeRelativeWeighting (8-bit integer)"                            
[47] "Corner Coordinates:"                                                                              
[48] "Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)"                                                                    
[49] "Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)"                                                                    
[50] "Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)"                                                                    
[51] "Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)"                                                                    
[52] "Center      (  256.0,  256.0)"  

#Returns HDF subdataset names for standardized files.
> sds <- get_subdatasets("3B43.19980101.7.HDF")

# precipiction is the first subset, convert to tif
> gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = "NPP2000.tif")


       
# Load the new .tif
       
> rast <- raster("NPP2000.tif") 

> rast
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1440, 400, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 400, 0, 1440  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : /media/ahmed/Volume/ITCZ_algo_dev/ITCZ_Algorithm/NPP2000.tif 
names      : NPP2000 

> med<-raster::as.matrix(rast)
> dim(med)
[1] 1440  400
> plot(rast)
```

[image: The plotted raster layer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `terra` like this

```
library(terra)
# terra version 1.2.5
x <- rast("3B43.19980101.7.HDF")
#Warning message:
#[rast] unknown extent
 
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1440, 400, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.0025, 0.0006944444  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#sources     : 3B43.19980101.7.HDF:0  
#              3B43.19980101.7.HDF:1  
#              3B43.19980101.7.HDF:2  
#names       : 0, 1, 2
```

Now fix the data

```
y <- t(x)
z <- flip(y, "v")
ext(z) <- c(-180, 180, -50, 50)
z

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 400, 1440, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       :           0,           1,           2 
#min values  :  0.00000000,  0.00144434,  0.00000000 
#max values  :   1.5933868,   0.5838504, 100.0000000 

plot(z)
```

[image]

If you only care about one of the layers you can do, for example to get the second one,

```
x <- rast("3B43.19980101.7.HDF", 2)
z <- flip(t(x), "v")
ext(z) <- c(-180, 180, -50, 50)
```

Comment: You actually saved my life! Many thanks! Very much appreciated!

Comment: I have another Q: I try to install your nice libraray by: `install.packages("terra", configure.args = "--with-gdal-config=/home/ahmed/miniconda2/pkgs/libgdal-3.1.2-hb2a6f5f_2/bin/gdal-config")`. It stops at: `checking for gdal.h... no
configure: error: gdal.h not found in given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’ ` I have miniconda installed.

Comment: I assume you need to install GDAL first. Here are some instructions for installation: https://github.com/rspatial/terra